# Convert list of indices and values to matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of indices and values as follows

```
1 3 2.1
2 1 1.1
2 2 0.2
2 3 0.4
1 2 0.3
1 1 3.2
3 3 4.0
3 1 0.2
3 2 0.1
```

where the first two columns represent the (i,j)'th index of a matrix that I wish to populate with the corresponding value. That is, I want the above to generate the following matrix

```
3.2 0.3 2.1
1.1 0.2 0.4
0.2 0.1 4.0
```

Is there a way to do this in R without resorting to a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create a `matrix` of 0s and fill the values of the third column of dataset with the indices from the first two columns

```
m1  <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
m1[as.matrix(df1[1:2])] <- df1[,3]
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  3.2  0.3  2.1
#[2,]  1.1  0.2  0.4
#[3,]  0.2  0.1  4.0
```

---

Or with `sparseMatrix`

```
library(Matrix)
sparseMatrix(i = df1$col1, j = df1$col2, x = df1$col3)
# 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
            
#[1,] 3.2 0.3 2.1
#[2,] 1.1 0.2 0.4
#[3,] 0.2 0.1 4.0
```

---

Another option is `xtabs`

```
xtabs(col3 ~ col1 + col2, df1)
# col2
#col1   1   2   3
#   1 3.2 0.3 2.1
#   2 1.1 0.2 0.4
#   3 0.2 0.1 4.0
```

---

If we need an efficient option may be `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), col1 ~ col2, value.var = 'col3')
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  spread(col2, col3)
```

NOTE: All the methods work even if there are unequal number of indices

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    col2 = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), col3 = c(2.1, 
    1.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 3.2, 4, 0.2, 0.1)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: `xtabs` is pretty clean, that does the trick. Do you know which solution is more efficient?

Comment: @jonem data.table may be more efficient

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that the data type is 'xtabs', how do I convert it to just numbers? Sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology.

Comment: @jonem It is just the attribute.  You can change it to NULL `attr(out, "call") <- NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You may bring the matrix in right order and apply `matrix`.

```
matrix(m[order(m[,2], m[,1]), 3], 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  3.2  0.3  2.1
# [2,]  1.1  0.2  0.4
# [3,]  0.2  0.1  4.0
```

***Data***

```
m <- structure(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
2, 2.1, 1.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 3.2, 4, 0.2, 0.1), .Dim = c(9L, 3L
))
```

Comment: This only works if every cell location is guaranteed to occur exactly once and once only in your input - otherwise you get gaps or ragged entries.

Comment: @smci sure, OP's sample suggests complete data in this respect, though.